# react-native-router-flux reset StackNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a problem with react-native-router-flux, I want to reset my stack navigation when I change of tab. I use backToinitial but I need to click two times for reset my nav someone know why ?

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Tabs
                  key="root"
                  tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}
                  backToInitial={true}
                >
              <Scene key="osu" title="OSU" icon={TabIcon}>

                <Scene 
                  key="scarlet"
                  component={ScarletScreen}
                  title="Scarlet"
                />
                <Scene
                  key="gray"
                  component={GrayScreen}
                  title="Gray"
                />
              </Scene>

              <Scene key="vu" title="VU" icon={TabIcon}>

                <Scene 
                  key="blue"
                  component={BlueScreen}
                  title="Blue"
                />
                <Scene
                  key="black"
                  component={BlackScreen}
                  title="Black"
                />

              </Scene>
            </Tabs>
        </Router>
      );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I put in a PR to fix this if anyone else comes across it.

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/pull/3131/

If you don't want to wait for for fix you can add an override to your Tabs by adding this prop:

```
 <Tabs 
   tabBarOnPress={({ scene, jumpToIndex }) => {
      const { route, focused } = scene;
      const { key } = route;
      if(focused) return;
      if (key === 'homeTab' && route.routes.length > 1) {
         Actions['firstSceneUnderHomeTab']({ type: ActionConst.replace });
      } else {
        //normally navigate to a tab
        jumpToIndex(scene.index);
      }
   }}>
```

Make sure you don't have backToInitial set on any of your tabs however because the latest version has a bug where backToInitial overwrites your tabBarOnPress. Hopefully will be updated soon.